# YQL scrape entire website/domain

Tags: screen-scraping, html-content-extraction, yql

I'm trying to scape back a set of links and content from a domain.

The Query in google would be

```
"site:www.newswebsite.com search_term"
```

I've seen some close stuff to getting this working, but I can't seem to quite get a search working across a whole website, and then filter by the search term.

Is this possible without a custom data table?

Comment: This seems to be getting me closer,

    select html,abstract from search.web where query="newswebsite.com search_term"

Comment: And Further, 

select title,abstract,url from search.web where query="newswebsite.com search_term"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to the bottom of it in the end.

```
select title,abstract,url,date from search.web(0) where query="search_term" and sites="www.website1.com,www.website2.com,www.website3.com" | sort (field='date') | reverse()
```

This searches 3 sites, orders by date, and newest first. There is an alternate way to reverse the sort, but this seems to work for now. I think it's descending=true within the sort (field='date',descending='true')

Very useful, even if I do say so myself.

Answer (score 0):

Christian Heilmann just wrote a fairly nice writeup on YQL and getting information back from an HTML datasource on the [24ways website](http://24ways.org/2009/the-web-is-your-cms).